# Unable to add TKInter value to MySQL table

Tags: python, mysql, sql, tkinter

I am trying to add records to a Mysql table using python query. To add the records I have made a GUI using tkinter and using tkinter "ENRTY" function.

Here is the code

```
mydb=msc.connect(host="localhost",user="VAIBHAV",password="123456",database="homework")
   
mycursor=mydb.cursor()
                                          
mycursor.execute("insert into RECORDS values(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)",(adm_I,name_I,Class_I,fh_I,mh_I,adress_I,phone_no_I,email_id_I))                                                 
print("Records added")

mycursor.commit()
mycursor.close()
```

But I run the program and the execute the function Python I get this error:

[image: IMAGE OF THE ERROR]

I don't know what is going wrong

Comment: It should be `mydb.commit()`

Comment: Hey why are you shouting?? Please don't SHOUT uppercase sentences are considered as shouting and it's rude

Comment: You need to store the value of the TKInter entry, not the entry itself.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code or errors. Images aren't searchable, and the visually impaired can't read them at all.

Comment: Well try out `adm_I.get()` and do same for other widgets, make sure to post a little more code of creation of the entry widget